# Implementacion MVVM + recyclerview + fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, mvvm

Necesito ayuda con un problema, soy nuevo en Android.
Mi problema es a la hora de la implementación de el viewmodel con recyclerview. No estoy entendiendo la idea del viewmodel. Estoy utilizando MVVM + FRAGMENTS + RECYCLERVIEW
Adjunto el código realizado hasta ahora.

**FRAGMENT**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {


   val mAdapter: HomeAdapter = HomeAdapter()
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        val listapersonas: RecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        val personaAdapter = HomeAdapter()
        listapersonas.adapter = personaAdapter
        listapersonas.setHasFixedSize(true)
        personaAdapter.personas = HomeModel.data


        return root
    }


}
```

**ADAPTADOR RECYCLER VIEW**

```
class HomeAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    var personas = listOf<HomeModel>()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.lista_personas, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val persona = personas[position]
        holder.bind(persona)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = personas.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tituloPersona: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.titulo_persona)
        val fechaNacimiento: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.fecha_nacimiento)

        fun bind(modelo: HomeModel) {
            tituloPersona.text = modelo.nombre
            fechaNacimiento.text = modelo.fechaNacimiento
        }

    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
data class HomeModel(
    var nombre: String,<br/>
    var imagenId: Int,<br/>
    var fechaNacimiento: String,<br/>
) {
    companion object {<br/>
        val data<br/>
            get() = listOf(<br/>
                HomeModel("Brian", 2, "1998-19-11"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Ezequiel", 3, "121221"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Alaniz", 8, "1020012"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Jorge", 10, "2121221"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Jose", 22, "2002110"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Martin", 22, "123456"),<br/>
                HomeModel("Lorenzo", 22, "0000111"),<br/>


            )
    }
}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val personas = MutableLiveData<HomeModel>()
    

}
```

Comment: cuál es la pregunta? No veo ninguna